# number theory(trace)

Tags: number-theory

Set $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}.$ Use the trace $T=T^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}$ to show that $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}[\alpha].$ Hint $\sqrt{3}=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3$ show that $a=b=0$ and calculate $T(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\alpha})$ then show that $c=0$, finally get a contradiction.

Comment: So, what do you get when you calculate the trace on both sides of the $\sqrt3$ equation? Much better if you show us you have actually tried something, than if you just dump a question here – helps us to know exactly where your difficulty is.

Comment: I dont know how to find the trace?

Comment: Why didn't you say so? The trace is the sum of the conjugates. Do you know what conjugates are?

Comment: yes, so you should find the conjugates.

Comment: Yes, you should find the conjugates. Do you know what the conjugates of $\sqrt3$ are? Do you know what the conjugates of $\root4\of2$ are?

Comment: What is the trace of $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: the trace of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is $0$

Comment: The conjugates of $\sqrt3$ are $\sqrt3$ and $-\sqrt3$, so the trace is ...

Answer (score 0):

Set $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}.$ $T=T^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}_{\mathbb{Q}}.$\
    Suppose $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha],$ then $\sqrt{3}=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3,$ where $ a,b,c$ and $d\in \mathbb{Q}.$ Then $T(\sqrt{3})=T(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3)=T(a)+T(b\alpha)+T(c\alpha^2)+T(d\alpha^3)=T(a)+bT(\alpha)+cT(\alpha^2)+dT(\alpha^3).$ We have $Irr(\alpha,\mathbb{Q})=X^4-2$, $Irr(\alpha^2,\mathbb{Q})=X^2-2$, $Irr(\alpha^3,\mathbb{Q})=X^4-8$, $Irr(\sqrt{3},\mathbb{Q})=X^2-3$ and $Irr(\sqrt{3},\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}])=X-\sqrt{3}.$
 As $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha],$ then $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]\subset\mathbb{Q}[\alpha].$ Therefore $T(\sqrt{3})=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]}\left(T_{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\sqrt{3})\right)=4a.$ Since $T(a)=4a,$ $T(\alpha)=\alpha+(-\alpha)+(-i\alpha)+i\alpha=0,$  $T(\alpha^2)=\sqrt{2}+(-\sqrt{2})=0$ and $T(\alpha^3)=\alpha^3+(-\alpha^3)+(-i\alpha^3)+i\alpha=0.$
But $T_{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3},$ then $T(\sqrt{3})=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]}(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}+(-\sqrt{3})=0.$ Therefore $a=0.$
Thus $\sqrt{3}=b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3.$ Let $\beta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\alpha}$, then $\beta=b+c\alpha+d\alpha^2.$ As $\sqrt{3}$ and $\alpha$ belong to $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, then $\beta\in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}[\beta]\subset\mathbb{Q}[\alpha].$
Hence $T(\beta)=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\beta]}\left(T_{\mathbb{Q}[\beta]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\beta)\right)=4b.$ But $T_{\mathbb{Q}[\beta]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\beta)=\beta,$ because $Irr(\beta,\mathbb{Q}[\beta])=X-\beta.$
Therefore $T(\beta)=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\beta]}(\beta)=0,$ since $Irr(\beta,\mathbb{Q})=X^4-\frac{9}{2}.$ Then $b=0.$
Thus $\beta=c\alpha+d\alpha^2.$ Let $\gamma=\frac{\beta}{\alpha},$ then $\gamma=c+d\alpha.$ As $\beta$ and $\alpha$ belong to $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha],$ then $\gamma\in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]\subset\mathbb{Q}[\alpha].$ 
Hence $T(\gamma)=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]}\left(T_{\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\gamma)\right)=4c.$ But $T_{\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]}^{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]}(\gamma)=\gamma,$ since $Irr(\gamma,\mathbb{Q}[\gamma])=X-\gamma.$
Therefore $T(\gamma)=T_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]}(\gamma)=0,$ since $Irr(\gamma,\mathbb{Q})=X^2-\frac{3}{2}.$ Then $c=0.$
Thus $\gamma=d\alpha,$ then $\sqrt{3}=d\alpha^3.$ If $d\ne0,$ then $\sqrt{2}=\frac{3}{2d^2}\in \mathbb{Q}.$ A contradiction. 
Hence $\alpha\notin \mathbb{Q}[\alpha].$